# Receiving no output of emailmessage subject when passing object to a string function

Tags: vb.net, string, function, exchangewebservices

### VB.Net 2012

I have the following function

```
Public Function getTaskTitle(message As EmailMessage) As String
    Return message.Subject.ToString
End Function
```

During a loop thru an message itemView, for each message I call this function.

```
    For Each item In FindItemsResults
        Console.Writeline(getTaskTitle(item).ToString)
    Next
```

But nothing gets returned. I tried a couple of things but it is only working like this,

```
    For Each item In FindItemsResults
        Console.Writeline(item.Subject)
    Next
```

Which I do not preffer because the code will not be separated as it should.

Can someone tell me how this might be possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: What is a type for `FindItemsResults` ?

Comment: FindItemsResults<TItem> class is a class from Exchange WebService API.

Comment: Make sure that 'item' is of type "EmailMessage" also try your luck by removing '.tostring' while returning, Because message Title is by default in String format.

Comment: The type is also Exchange.Webservices.Data.FindItemResults (Of Item)

Comment: I removed toString but still not working, initially i didnt use it too but only tried if it works..

Comment: @JacobSiemaszko: so, it's not possible, because what you are receiving at the function is "EmailMessage" object, but you are not actually sending it at call. Try doing typecasting in a for loop of 'item' before sending it to function as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense.

Are you binding the messages in `FindItemResults` ?

```
item = EmailMessage.Bind(..)
```

Try changing item to type `EmailMessage`on For Each and remove `ToString`

```
Public Function getTaskTitle(message As EmailMessage) As String
    Return message.Subject
End Function

For Each item as EmailMessage In FindItemsResults
        Console.Writeline(getTaskTitle(item))
    Next
```

Comment: Why is it neccessary to bind the message item ?

Comment: Binds to an existing e-mail message and loads its first class properties. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd634030(v=exchg.80).aspx. By the way try only changing what I wrote you first

Comment: @JacobSiemaszko: Because "EmailMessage.Bind" this returns the object of "EmailMessage" class.